# TableView not reloading properly

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am making an settings screen in which you can select stations via a uisearchbar. I have a sectioned tableview, with the first letter of a station as the header and every station is categorized by it's first letter. So far so good. 
I habe 2 NSMutableArray's with, per section, the stations. One is the unfiltered array (Which I use when I don't have it filtered) and the other one, when I am searching for something. (I do this via a predicate). On every keypress on the keyboard I do a [self.tableView reloadData]; this works, HOWEVER the scrollview stays too long! So you can scroll way past how many results are actually in the selected array. This causes a crash, because it's trying to get objects that don't exist.

So it seems like the tableview isn't counting the array right or something? 
Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Here is some code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (self.searching) {
        return [self.tableFilterd count];
    } else {
        return [self.tableData count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Rows for section");
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (self.searching) {
        NSLog(@"Editing section: %i, count %i", section, [[self.tableFilterd objectAtIndex:section] count]);
        return [[self.tableFilterd objectAtIndex:section] count];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not editing");
        return [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    SettingsHeaderCell *cell = [[[SettingsHeaderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"] autorelease];

    cell.labelLetter.text = [[self.tableLetters objectAtIndex:section] capitalizedString];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 52;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    SettingsCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[SettingsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (self.searching) {
        StationObject *object = (StationObject *)[[self.tableFilterd objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setStationObject:object];
    } else {
        StationObject *object = (StationObject *)[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setStationObject:object];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you are using NSArray to populate the tableView. Actually you cannot add or remove items in nsarray once if u added. so your array is always same and it is not filtered i think. try to use nsmutablearray if you update your array anyhow..

Comment: Oh no, it's an NSMutableArray

Comment: could you post the code that where you are populating your filteredarray

Comment: Yes, please post code where you generate your "tableFiltered" array after each key press. Perhaps there are more items in that array then you are expecting?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/NMwGn40G

Comment: You've got NSLogs in there, what are they printing?

Comment: The ones in numberOfRowsInSection are at first logging "Not editing" and when i tap the search bar, "Editing section: 40, count 11" bla bla, 

Hey I just noticed, the cells dissapear from the screen but the logging keeps saying there are objects in the array. This only happens on the first time I start searching. When I press the cross to empty the searchbar and start searching again it does work

Comment: Seems like something with my predicate isn't working... Investigating.

It seems like it only works when I cleared the filtered array one time before

Comment: -- Okay I fixed it, when I clear, and rebuild the filter array with fresh data when I first start searching it starts working. I am not sure why...

Comment: I guess returning a reused UITableViewCell for a section header is a  very bad idea - why don't you just return a plain UIView (or a UILabel since you only need a letter)? Why trying to reuse a tableViewCell and return it when you only need a UIView?

Comment: @TimWachter does it work now? if so, add an answer plz

Answer (score 0):

You might have solved this by now but I suspect you aren't emptying either arrays. In the method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

//Remove all objects first
[self.tableFiltered removeAllObjects];
[self.tableData removeAllObjects];
```

Also you only need to call  [self.tableView reloadData]; in textDidChange, not in the other three methods. Hope this helps.